# can we use % symbol in apex controller?

Tags: math

When I'm using `%` symbol it is showing the below error message:

> Found punctuation symbol or operator '%' that isn't valid in Apex.

Answer (score 11):

In most languages that use it, it represents the modulus operation.

In APEX, you use [Math.Mod()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm)

```
if (Math.Mod(x, 2) == 0) {
    system.debug(x + ' is even');
}
```

[APEX Expression Operators Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) shows that there is no definition of a `%` operator.

Comment: thank u it is working. but i want to know more information about these symbols is there any examples?

Comment: All of the information you'll need is in the links I posted. The first one shows the math class and everything that it can do and the second shows all of the operators that are supported in salesforce alongside descriptions for them.

Comment: @user57471 Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check box. This is how you show the community that this answer worked for you and others with the same question will know what the right answer is.